# function that takes a list of years and returns a list with the closest year that is not a leap year. [1995,1750,2018] return [1994,1751,2019]

Tags: python

```
def is_leap(year):
    return (((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0)) or (year % 400 == 0))

def _notLeap(year):
    return ((year % 4 !=0) and (year % 400 !=0))

def findNonNextLeapYears(yearBounds):
    k=1
    lst=[]
    Years=[i+k for i in yearBounds]
    for i in Years:
        if is_leap(i):
            lst= [i-2 for i in Years] 
        else:
            _notLeap(i)
            lst =[i for i in Years]
        return lst
```

```
>>>findNonNextLeapYears([1995,1750,2018])
[1996, 1751, 2019]
```

but it doesn't return 1994

Comment: use this [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap) it will make your life easier

Comment: -AMC how i get it to return 1994 instead of 1996? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code actually return `[1994, 1749, 2017]` but it has some issues  1) your returned list will apply the same offset to all years based on the calculation for the first one, 2) _notLeap doesn't apply the 100 year condition and is never actually used

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @Alain T. and @ AMC okay thank you